# Understanding OS dispatching between different processors

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, multicore

If I have a class

```
class A{
  A(){
   getcontext(context);
   makecontext(context, fun1, etc)
   put context pointer on queue
   }

  fun1(args){
    something
  }
 }
```

In I make an instance of class A in Thread1 running on CPU1, and then try to pop the context off the queue and swap it in from thread2 on CPU2, will there be a problem because the object was instantiated in the stack of Thread1 in CPU1 and hence the pointer to fun1 which is attacked to this context is not reachable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The whole point of threads is that they share all memory.

Comment: Hey thanks,

So I was actually trying to implement a thread library using context switches. my doubt then was how would i ensure that the memory is shared amongst them? It might have been misleading for me to say thread 1 and thread 2 here.

Comment: @Achint There's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: Ok. I guess my confusion was that every context would have a stack associated with it. In the current context which instantiates A(a thread), the object would be saved on the stack of that context? So when I attach a function to a new context, its basically telling the program counter to start with that function right? which is a member of an object stored on another contexts stack?

Comment: @Achint Yes, that's basically it.

Comment: But they shouldn't be accessing each others stacks? Not that it's enforced that they can't but that they shouldn't?

Comment: @Achint It's perfectly normal for threads to access each other's stacks. The whole point of threads is that they share all memory. Just make sure an object doesn't get destroyed when another thread might access it.

Comment: @Achint Say you buy each of your kids their own car. Should they be accessing each other's cars? Well, not usually. That's why they each have their own. But certainly when they're cooperating, there might be any number of exceptions. There might be an agreement that the tools are kept in one particular car and if someone else needs the tools, they go to that car to get it. So long as they're cooperating, the rules can be whatever makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the answer is yes and no.   All threads share the same memory.  If more than 1 thread accesses the object, you need to be careful to synchronize access between thread.   That's the yes part.

The no part is when you said stack of thread 1.   Stack variables are local to a function.   If the function returns, the local variables are no longer valid.  You don't show quite enough code for me to see where context gets created, and if the function that allocate the object on the stack waits until thread 2 finishes.